# Numeric traits itk

Tags: c++, numeric, traits, itk

I came across the following statement:

```
PixelType label = itk::NumericTraits<PixelType>::One;
```

It seems to be related to numric traits, which documentation I have read [here](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1NumericTraits.html), but didn't yet get the idea of the statement.

Can you kindly just describe to me what the statement means?

Answer (score 0):

`One` is a static variable in class template `itk:NumericTraits`. There might be an explicit specialization of it somewhere in `itk`

```
template<> PixelType itk::NumericTraits<PixelType>::One = ...;
```

It defines a value of `one` for `PixelType` type.

Answer (score 0):

It's the multiplicative identity of the value type you're using in the template parameter.

Where any value `v` of type `T` follows:

```
v * 1 = 1 * v = v
```

It's calculated at compile time and can be accessed as a static member of type `T`